Clang command execution failed
I have just begun Android development and am using Android Studio.
I was going through the tutorial at https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-first-app#7
The code generates proper preview but when I run it gives the error "Clang Command Execution failed". I am attaching the screenshot of the error below.

Please help with the error.
Thanks!

Clang is only use in case you create a project with C/C++ code. For Java/Kotlin it is not relevant. Most likely you selected the wrong project template when creating a new project. Don't use anything with "C++" in it's name.
